# Logging to file in Scala/akka: ClassNotFoundException: akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter

Tags: scala, logging, akka, logback

I have searched quite a bit but could not find a working solution. Could someone please help me?

```
akka {
     event-handlers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"]
     loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
     loglevel = "DEBUG"
     logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"
     stdout-loglevel = "WARNING"
     actor {
       debug {
         receive = on
         lifecycle = off
       }
     }
}
```

and I have added the following to `build.sbt` in the hope that one of them solves the issue:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq (
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.1",   // akka actors
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.3",  //logback, in order to log to file
  "com.typesafe.scala-logging" % "scala-logging-slf4j_2.11" % "2.1.2",
  "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-slf4j_2.11" % "2.4.1",   // needed for logback to work
  // and my other dependencies
)
```

and I have tried with different suggestions I found for `logback.xml`, the last of which is:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>logs/filename.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %level %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <maxIndex>10</maxIndex>
            <FileNamePattern>logs/filename.log.%i.gz</FileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>20MB</maxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
    </appender>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

---

EDIT: My complete dependencies are as follows (ps: I currently have both `lift` and `salat` for de/serialization, but that's a different story):

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq (
  "org.scala-lang" % "scalap" % scalaVersion.value, 
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.1",   
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.3",  
  "com.typesafe.scala-logging" % "scala-logging-slf4j_2.11" % "2.1.2",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % "2.4.1",  
  "com.github.sstone" %% "amqp-client" % "1.5", 
  "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "2.6.2",
  "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json-ext" % "2.6.2",    
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.4" % "test",
  "com.novus" %% "salat" % "1.9.9"
)
```

Comment: You have "scalalogging" for scala 2.10 and "akka-slf4j" for scala 2.11, you should probably choose one scala version.

Comment: updated scalalogging to 2.11. This is actually not needed based on akka docs. I added it because someone somewhere was suggesting it. Still doesn't work anyway.

Comment: Actually "and my other dependencies" is the key here. I had similar problems when I tried to mix Play 2.4.2 and Akka 2.4. Could you share what other dependencies do you use? When I was trying to figure out the problem, External Libraries in "Project" tool window in IntelliJ IDEA helped me a lot. I had some conflicting versions of libraries.

Comment: @PavelKudinov please see the edited question.

Comment: I see play has updated their dependency on akka to 2.4 with play 2.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you use `"com.novus" %% "salat" % "1.9.9"` which depends on `salat-util % 1.9.9`, which [depends](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.novus/salat-util_2.11/1.9.9) on `org.slf4j % slf4j-api % 1.7.2`. Akka `"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % "2.4.1"` [depends](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-slf4j_2.11/2.4.1) on 1.7.12. Make sure that you need the whole salat package. Probably you could find a way of using only part of it, or configure logging in different way, or wait for update from Salat developers.

Comment: Thanks Pavel for your answer. So I added the `akka-slf4j` one just for logging. Does it mean if I remove the `akka-slf4j` dependency, it should pick up the one from `salat` and fly?

Comment: I don't think you can remove `akka-slf4j` dependency, because you are using things like `akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger`. I don't really have a good solution for you, just identified a problem. I would suggest to play around different dependencies, or use something instead of `salat`...

Comment: OK. I accept your answer, even though as you said it is not a solution! :)

Comment: Salat maintainer here. If someone is still having a problem with this, please open an issue or PR with the project, we are doing small releases as needed for issues like this.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to solve these kind of problems is always **see the dependency tree** and figure out whats going on there, (its very important be it `maven` or `sbt`)

See how many slf4j dependencies you have. (I can see conflicting dependencies `slf4j-api:1.6.0`, `slf4j-api:1.7.2`, `slf4j-api:1.7.12`)

```
sbt dependencyTree

[info]   +-com.novus:salat_2.11:1.9.9 [S]
[info]   | +-com.novus:salat-core_2.11:1.9.9 [S]
[info]   | | +-com.novus:salat-util_2.11:1.9.9 [S]
[info]   | | | +-org.scala-lang:scalap:2.11.5
[info]   | | | | +-org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.11.5 [S]
[info]   | | | |   +-org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.11:1.0.1 (evicted by: 1.0.3)
[info]   | | | |   +-org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.11:1.0.3 [S]
[info]   | | | |   +-org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.11:1.0.1 (evicted by: 1.0.3)
[info]   | | | |   +-org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.11:1.0.3 [S]
[info]   | | | |   +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.11.5 [S]
[info]   | | | |   
[info]   | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.0 (evicted by: 1.7.12)
[info]   | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
[info]   | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.2 (evicted by: 1.7.12)

[info]   +-ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3
[info]   | +-ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.3
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7 (evicted by: 1.7.12)

[info]   | | +-org.mongodb:casbah-core_2.11:2.7.1 [S]
[info]   | |   +-com.github.nscala-time:nscala-time_2.11:1.0.0 [S]
[info]   | |   | +-joda-time:joda-time:2.3
[info]   | |   | +-org.joda:joda-convert:1.2
[info]   | |   | 
[info]   | |   +-org.mongodb:casbah-commons_2.11:2.7.1 [S]
[info]   | |   | +-com.github.nscala-time:nscala-time_2.11:1.0.0 [S]
[info]   | |   | | +-joda-time:joda-time:2.3
[info]   | |   | | +-org.joda:joda-convert:1.2
[info]   | |   | | 
[info]   | |   | +-org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:2.12.1
[info]   | |   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.0 (evicted by: 1.7.12)
[info]   | |   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
[info]   | |   | 
[info]   | |   +-org.mongodb:casbah-query_2.11:2.7.1 [S]
[info]   | |   | +-com.github.nscala-time:nscala-time_2.11:1.0.0 [S]
[info]   | |   | | +-joda-time:joda-time:2.3
[info]   | |   | | +-org.joda:joda-convert:1.2
[info]   | |   | | 
[info]   | |   | +-org.mongodb:casbah-commons_2.11:2.7.1 [S]
[info]   | |   | | +-com.github.nscala-time:nscala-time_2.11:1.0.0 [S]
[info]   | |   | | | +-joda-time:joda-time:2.3
[info]   | |   | | | +-org.joda:joda-convert:1.2
[info]   | |   | | | 
[info]   | |   | | +-org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:2.12.1
[info]   | |   | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.0 (evicted by: 1.7.12)
[info]   | |   | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
[info]   | |   | | 
[info]   | |   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.0 (evicted by: 1.7.12)
[info]   | |   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
[info]   | |   | 
[info]   | |   +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.0 (evicted by: 1.7.12)
[info]   | |   +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12

[info]   | +-com.novus:salat-util_2.11:1.9.9 [S]
[info]   |   +-org.scala-lang:scalap:2.11.5
[info]   |   | +-org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.11.5 [S]
[info]   |   |   +-org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.11:1.0.1 (evicted by: 1.0.3)
[info]   |   |   +-org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.11:1.0.3 [S]
[info]   |   |   +-org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.11:1.0.1 (evicted by: 1.0.3)
[info]   |   |   +-org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.11:1.0.3 [S]
[info]   |   |   +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.11.5 [S]
[info]   |   |   
[info]   |   +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.0 (evicted by: 1.7.12)
[info]   |   +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
[info]   |   +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.2 (evicted by: 1.7.12)

[info]   +-com.typesafe.scala-logging:scala-logging-slf4j_2.11:2.1.2 [S]
[info]   | +-com.typesafe.scala-logging:scala-logging-api_2.11:2.1.2 [S]
[info]   | +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.11.5 [S]
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7 (evicted by: 1.7.12)

[info]   +-net.liftweb:lift-json-ext_2.11:2.6.2 [S]
[info]   | +-commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6
[info]   | +-joda-time:joda-time:2.1 (evicted by: 2.3)
[info]   | +-joda-time:joda-time:2.3
[info]   | +-net.liftweb:lift-common_2.11:2.6.2 [S]
[info]   | | +-org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.11:1.0.1 (evicted by: 1.0.3)
[info]   | | +-org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.11:1.0.3 [S]
[info]   | | +-org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.11:1.0.1 (evicted by: 1.0.3)
[info]   | | +-org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.11:1.0.3 [S]
[info]   | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.0 (evicted by: 1.7.12)
[info]   | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
[info]   | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.2 (evicted by: 1.7.12)
```

And to know what version is used,

```
$ sbt dependencyList
[info] org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
```

That way you can control which version you want and which you want to exclude,

eg. to exclude the `slf4j-api` version that `salat` uses

```
"com.novus" %% "salat" % "1.9.9" exclude("org.slf4j","slf4j-api")
```

### Note

add `addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void" % "sbt-dependency-graph" % "0.8.2")` to `project/plugins.sbt` to use `sbt dependencyTree`.

https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph#usage-instructions

Answer (score 3):

@Mahdi: Not sure if you were able to solve your problem, but I faced the same problem and figured out that the correct version of 
`"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % "2.4.0",` was not included in my build.sbt.

Comment: I don't remember what I did at the time, but thanks for the answer. Maybe someone will be able to use this answer.

Comment: This worked for me as well on scala 2.11 and akka 2.4.16