# Reading sbt dependency tree

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, dependency-management

I'm upgrading some libraries within a Play! project. During the process I'm trying to resolve errors like this:
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter`

Which I am assuming comes from incompatible transitive dependencies?

But I'm struggling to effectively use `sbt-dependency-graph` to help me track down the problem.

```
[info]   +-ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3
[info]   | +-ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.3
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7 (evicted by: 1.7.21)
```

Why are there 2 versions of `slf4j-api` listed

I'm assuming, the newer version (`1.7.21`) is taking precedence over `1.7.7` But then, why in some instances, do I see as many as 5 different versions of the same dependency (all but 1 evicted):

```
  | | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-ext:1.7.12
  | | | |   +-ch.qos.cal10n:cal10n-api:0.8.1
  | | | |   +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.2 (evicted by: 1.7.21)
  | | | |   +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.4 (evicted by: 1.7.21)
  | | | |   +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12 (evicted by: 1.7.21)
  | | | |   +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.2 (evicted by: 1.7.21)
  | | | |   +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21
```

Once the conflict is found -- do I need to upgrade all dependencies to be using the same version?

Is there another approach I should be taking?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34133715/logging-to-file-in-scala-akka-classnotfoundexception-akka-event-slf4j-slf4jlog

Answer (score 0):

Discovered that ["the SLF4J API is backward compatible for all versions"](https://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#compatibility). Despite `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` being called from an `slf4j`. So digging a little deeper:

Akka Kindly provides [binary compatibility rules](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/common/binary-compatibility-rules.html#binary-compatibility-rules-explained) which show that backwards compatibility is violated between major versions.

Looking at the dependency tree we were seeing different major versions of akka dependencies (2.3.x and 2.4.x): `com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.11:2.3.13 (evicted by: 2.4.11)` and `com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j_2.11:2.3.13`

Standardizing all akka dependencies around a major version fixed it:

Our original dependencies only provided the `"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.11"` and play was providing `"akka-slf4j" % "2.3.13"` transitively which was breaking binary compatibility.

```
+-com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j_2.11:2.3.13 [S]
| +-com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.11:2.3.13 (evicted by: 2.4.11)
```

Providing both `akka-slf4j` and `akka-actor` with the same major version solved this issue.